# Stapled Web-scoped feature depending on Site-scoped feature: possible?

Tags: feature, feature-activation, feature-stapling, feature-dependency

I have three features in a solution:

- A Web-scoped feature (**A**): has a `FeatureActivated` call to set up a site
- A Site-scoped feature (**B**): contains WebParts **A** uses
- A stapling feature (**C**): staples **A** to a site definition

Is it possible to have a Feature Dependency from **A** onto **B** that will cause **B** to be automatically activated? I've tried it in various combinations using the standard Feature Dependency section on feature **A**, but the activation always fails.

If this isn't possible using the standard method, is there an alternative method I can use?

Comment: This will explain to you why it's not working:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543162.aspx

Comment: @Michael: Gosh, that is a good *answer*...

Comment: :) Well I didn't feel it really helped you solve your question rather merely confirmed the reason for the behaviour you described.

Comment: @Michael: Well to be fair I rolled two questions into one; the first part was "will this work?", to which the answer was "no".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already having a feature receiver for (A), you could easily in your FeatureActivated method of (A) in code activate feature (B) on the site collection level. Just a few lines of code...

Comment: +1 It's a fair point, and I have briefly looked at SPSite.Features.Add (if that's what you're referring to). I was hoping to use the standard method, or at least understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Stuart, see Michaels comment on why it's not working.

Comment: Fair enough. Since your answer helps me work around the issue, I'll mark this as accepted. Obviously I'll still upvote Michael's answer if he takes the massive hint. :)